# Is there a way to make dynamic paint affect the reaction diffusion from tissue?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I've been experimenting with the tissues reaction-diffusion, but I can't find a way to render the animation so I'm trying to control it with the dynamic paint, using some spheres to paint, but the reaction-diffusion doesn't seem to recognize it. Is there a way to make this work or is it not the best way to render an animation with reaction-diffusion?

Comment: What is it you would like to do with dynamic paint? Or are you simply trying to find some way to visualize what reaction diffusion is doing?

Comment: Yes, I just dont find a way to control the reaction diffusion, so a thought i could do it with a brush so that I can repeat the animation for a render

Comment: If only visualizing is the main goal, I can think of a couple ways. Thing is that reaction diffusion (as far as I understand) is *creating* vertex group data, so we can only use this information in dynamic paint or other modifiers to visualize what the data being generated is doing.

Comment: It seems that the animation option is not working with new versions of blender

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to *visualize* reaction diffusion, it takes a few steps but it seems to work I guess. Unfortunately, it does not seem that dynamic paint will directly work to *control* reaction diffusion, but we can use other ways to visualize it.

Starting with a densely subdivided quad-sphere, I have set up reaction diffusion and painted some random pattern on *vertex group B* with animation running. One thing I am also doing here is adding a few keyframes in the *scale* parameter throughout the timeline to add a bit of variation in the animation.

Here are my settings:

[image]

- *Bake the reaction diffusion before moving on.*

---

In object mode, make a copy of the object, and **do not move it**. 
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The copy and original must be in the same place for the next step to work properly.

---

In *Weight Paint* again, first select the original object, then select the copy and go to [*Weights>transfer weights*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/editing.html#transfer-weights) to copy the weights from the original to copy. This will copy the reaction diffusion from the original mesh to the copy, also allowing the animated weights to be used in modifiers in object mode.

Now you will be able to use the vertex groups with any combination of modifiers, such as displace, mask, etc.

For example, here is the quadsphere with just a displace modifier using the *B* vertex group.

[image]

Here is the .blend if you would like to inspect it

[image]

Comment: I haven't find any version with Cache ... may I ask what blender version contains such feature?

Comment: @vklidu I use the dev version of tissue from [here](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue)